# Make discord bot post live twitter feed(tweet) updates [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, twitter, bots, discord, discord.js

So I want to post **live tweet updates using my discord bot**.
What I need is something like IFTTT (but using my bot) ..
I researched the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/getting-started) a lot but could not make out a way to trigger when a new tweet is posted .. Currently I have to trigger using a command ..

Code snippet:

```
if(cmd===`${prefix}tweet`){
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: 'PulkitSinghss', count: 1, include_rts: false, exclude_replies: true }, function(error, tweets, response)
{
  if (!error)
  {
      let id = tweets[0].id_str ;
      message.channel.send(`https://twitter.com/PulkitSinghss/status/${id}`);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
}
```

The documentation has something on [User activity](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/overview) but I couldn't figure how to use it and also it seems that it will only allow for 1 user but I want to do for multiple...

Any insight is more than welcome!
P.S. First post on the site let me know if I miss something important!

Comment: Hey Ken, this question seems a bit too broad in scope. I would really dig into their `How to get access` section from the User Activity doc link you posted. When you find you have a more specific question in the process feel free to come back and ask it as well.

Comment: I figured it out myself .. Thanks for looking

Comment: Ken you should post the relevant code you used that helped you figure it out as an answer on this question. This is useful to future readers with a similar or same problem and you might help them out.

Comment: You should just use WebHooks, which are [built into Discord](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you could use the twitter-crawler npm module. This will allow you to get tweets from a specific user: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-crawler

Comment: The official API can also do that what I wanted was a trigger so that I dont have to call a command and the tweet update will be automatically posted ... Anyways I used a setinterval function to make it work the way i want .. Thanks for looking